# Pass along Azure AD authentication between apps

Tags: asp.net, azure, flask, oauth

I have two Apps in Azure where both require authentication through Azure AD to use.

App A is an ASP.Net website application.

App B is a python Flask REST web api application.

The users are supposed to navigate to App A and log in using their windows credentials.
App A needs to communicate with App B to perform some actions like for example fetch a list of items.

What happens now when sending a Get request to App B is that it returns HTML representing the login page that is generated by Azure.

I realize that I will need to pass along some OAuth token but have no idea how to generate this and receive it on App B end and use it to "unlock" the functionality.

So my question is, how to generate an OAuth token, pass it with api requests and handle it on python side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scenario is covered by the OAuth 2.0 on-behalf-of-flow and described in the Azure documentation on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow